# a way to assign headers when connecting to server sent events source or websocket

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm trying to connect to a server sent events source using event source api and websocket api but both of those don't offer any way to assign headers when sending the connection request. i need to be sending specific headers alongside auth header when making the request. is there any method/library/api that would help me achieve that?

i'm using vue.js and nuxt.js in my application

for example my connection code currently looks like this

```
      const eventSource = new EventSource(`${process.env.NUXT_APP_API_URL}/v1/notification/subscribe?clientUserId=${this.user.id}`);
      eventSource.onMessage = () => {
        //further code here
      }
    }
```

this request fails as i'm required to assign headers to the request body or it won't work, so how can i do that? or should the backend team lift the headers requiermnets on this particular kind of request?